# Google Maps Places Autocomplete - how to remove nearby results that don't translate into specific valid address?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am sorry if this has been answered before, I am searching up and down and can't find an answer for my specific problem. When using Google Maps Places Autocomplete for searching addresses, I would like to restrict results to specific streets, I want to remove any nearby indications.

Basically, I am building a form that looks like this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform.

I am using Brazilian streets for this example. If I type "Rua Ministro Viveiros de Castro", it will be the top result on the list. If I click on it, the form will recognize each of the address' componentes and translate them into the corresponding fields in the form. But the suggested results beneath the first 'Rua Ministro Viveiros de Castro' are nearby indications. In Portuguese (since my version is delivering content in Portuguese) says something like 'Rua Ministro Viveiros de Castro, close to number 87'. The issue for me is that if the user picks the suggested 'close to number xxx', the response from Google API won't contain the name of the state, city, neighborhood or street. The result won't translate to a valid address in the form. Actually in that type of situation, the only valid information I get is the Country, which translates to Brazil.

What I would like to do is to completely remove these 'close to number xxx' from the search that will frustrate the users because they won't translate to valid fields in the form.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: The thing is: the information is present. You do get the state, city, street, etc. Please check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/9JDa5/).